when call user control from from asp.net page it call only csharp not call jquery or java script function?
I work on asp.net project I face issue when call web user control from asp.net page it calling
success but script JavaScript or jQuery not called
so why scripts not called
only from debug page load user control only called on index.asp.net page
so function script  jQuery GET_ITO_PROJECTS_DASHBOARD not called or run why
only page load event c# of user control that called but script functions java script not called
index.aspx
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/WebPages/main.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="index.aspx.cs" Inherits="ITO.WebPages.index" EnableEventValidation="false" %>

<%@ Register Src="~/WebUserControls/UC_ProjectsDashboard.ascx" TagPrefix="uc2" TagName="UC_ProjectsDashboard" %>


<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <uc2:UC_ProjectsDashboard runat="server" />
</asp:Content>

user control UC_ProjectsDashboard.ascx
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="UC_ProjectsDashboard.ascx.cs" Inherits="ITO.WebUserControls.UC_ProjectsDashboard" %>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <div id="card-main_Index" class="card customCard card-outline-primary">
   
                     <div class="card-header">
                <h4 class="m-b-0 text-white card-title text-center">
                    <label id="lblTitle" runat="server" clientidmode="Static">Project Dashboard</label>
                </h4>
            </div>
             
                        <div class="card-body">

                         
                             
                        
                          
                              
                              
                               <div class="row" style="margin-top:10px;">
                             
                                <div class="col-12 col-lg-1">
                        
                                       </div>
                                   <div class="col-12 col-lg-5 gvResultmeeting-container hide">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                          <div class="card card-outline-success">
                                            <div class="card-header" style="background-color: #808080; font-size: 18px; padding: .75rem 1.25rem; font-weight: 600; height: 50px; color: #ffffff;">
                                              الاجتماعات التمهيديه
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="card-body">
                                                <table id="gvResultmeeting" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
                                                    <thead>
                                                    </thead>
                                                    <tbody>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                               
                        
                                <div class="col-12 col-lg-5  gvResultrequests-container hide">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="card card-outline-success">
                                            
                                                  <div class="card-header" style="background-color: #ffcc00; font-size: 18px; padding: .75rem 1.25rem; font-weight: 600; height: 50px; color: #ffffff;">
                                           الرد على الاستفسارات
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="card-body">
                                                <table id="gvResultrequests" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
                                                    <thead>
                                                    </thead>
                                                    <tbody>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                   <div class="col-12 col-lg-1">
                     
                                       </div>
                            </div>
                              <div class="row" style="margin-top:10px;">
                             
                                
                                   <div class="col-12 col-lg-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                          <div class="card card-outline-success">
                                            <div class="card-header" style="font-size: 18px; padding: .75rem 1.25rem; font-weight: 600;color: #ffffff;">
                                              المشروعات
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="card-body">
                                                <table id="gvResultprojects" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
                                                    <thead>
                                                    </thead>
                                                    <tbody>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                        
                             
                            </div>

                            </div>

                   
                
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>




<script>
    $(function () {
        debugger
        if ($("#txtP_PERM_ID").val() == "2059") {
            GET_ITO_PROJECTS_DASHBOARD();
        }
       
    });
</script>


For user controls, and in fact often for general controls, the jQuery selector will not work based on the "ID", since it often changed by asp.net pre-processing.
Hence, if you hit f12 (browser debug tools), you should see a error in your JavaScript code.
You want to use this syntax for the control id:
$("#<%=txtP_PERM_ID.ClientID%>")

So, your sample code likely is not working since the id of the control is being changed, and in most cases will be prefixed by the user control name, and then the control ID.
